# MVC3 structure routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have the following website structure:

(Section/SubSection/Pages/1..n)

```
e.g.
News/Current
News/Archive
News/Current/Pages/23
News/Archive/Pages/3
```

If the User goes to /News I want them to default to News/Current, otheriwse they see a page above.
Similarly,

```
Events/Latest
Events/London
Events/Latest/Pages/15
Events/Archive/Pages/4
```

I've got a controller setup for News and Events but how do I create the Actions and global.asax MapRoutes to handle my structure?

I don't want to use Areas for this, just simple Controllers and Actions please. Each View for a section will handle a ViewModel with a ContentPage property from the database?

So each Section will have a View, that will be populated with a ContentPage PartialView.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got two alternatives:

1. Use Areas
2. Create routes for `Archive` and `Latest` which makes the section after `Pages` a parameter containing the page.

**Update**

The route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MySuperRoute",
    "{controller}/{section1}/{section2}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "TheHandlingAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

And the action:

```
public ActionResult TheHandlingAction(string section1, string section2, int id)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not going down the Areas route for this. For option 2, that 'SubSection' level could have 1..n options not just Archive + Latest e.g. locations like London/Cardiff etc. I need an example of a MapRoute to handle these if you can? That's where I'm getting stuck along with sensible Controller Actions to match my route options above? Or do I just need one Action as they are all ContentPage essentially?

Comment: Any simple MapRoute examples anyone, for what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Will return a ContentPage from my DB, id=15 for whichever Section I'm in. e.g. `News/Current/Pages/23` or `Events/Cardiff/Pages/12`. Both those examples are linked pages from the top-level nav e.g. `News/Current` and `Events/Cardiff` respectively. Main point is that Current or Cardiff could be anything, so I don't want to use a separate action for all of those. What I need are routes to handle them all. So need to know how to write a MapRoute for my 2 options: 1) `/Section/SubSection` 2) `/Section/SubSection/Pages/Id` - hope this is clearer? Also the Controller Actions to go with them as well.

Comment: Is `Current`/`CarDiff` actions or controllers?

Comment: Neither. If I pass in News/Current/Cardiff or News/Any/Any I want the default Action in the News to be invoked which sends the User to wherever I decide within the Action. In that case News/Current. The second type: /Section(e.g. News)/SubSection/Pages/Id I want to go to a Pages Action in the News Controller, passing SubSection and ID as params.

Comment: That looks great, much appreciated.
What If section2 is a 'Pages' Action, do I need a separate MapRoute to handle that?

Comment: Yes. The specified route only works with the `TheHandlingAction` action. MVC takes the first matching route that it finds, so you should add them in the order you want to use them.